# Insert value from one table/column based on value from another table/column

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import a csv, unpivot the data and INSERT INTO `product_attribute` table.

I have a table called `attributes`

| attribute_id | attribute_name | attribute_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | colour | black |
| 2 | colour | green |
| 3 | colour | blue |
| 4 | size | small |
| 5 | size | medium |
| 6 | size | large |

I have a table called `products`

| product_id | sku | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test3 | 13 |
| 2 | test2 | 17 |
| 3 | test1 | 5 |

I have a table called `product_attribute` which is linked between both tables above.

| product_id | attribute_id |
| --- | --- |

the csv data is as follows which imports into a temp folder called `import`.

| sku | colour | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | black | small |
| test2 | green | large |
| test3 | blue | medium |

so far I have managed to unpivot the csv/table using the following query

```
SELECT sku, 'colour' attribute_name, colour attribute_value
FROM import
UNION ALL
SELECT sku, 'size' attribute_name, size attribute_value
FROM import
UNION ALL
```

the data then looks like this

| sku | attribute_name | attribute_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | colour | black |
| test2 | colour | green |
| test3 | colour | blue |
| test1 | size | small |
| test2 | size | large |
| test3 | size | medium |

I need to somehow add a INSERT INTO query with the unpivot query so the `product_attribute` table looks like the following

| product_id | attribute_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 5 |

I believe a subquery would help me achieve this but I'm not sure how to put it together when the value is based on another column.

Any help greatly appreciated thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your code in a subquery and join it to the two tables using the common columns.

```
INSERT INTO product_attribute(product_id, attribute_id)
    SELECT p.product_id, a.attribute_id
    FROM (
        SELECT sku, 'colour' attribute_name, colour attribute_value
        FROM import
        UNION ALL
        SELECT sku, 'size' attribute_name, size attribute_value
        FROM import
        UNION ALL
    ) as u
    JOIN products p   USING(sku)
    JOIN attributes a USING(attribute_name, attribute_value)
```